# Prepopulating DocuSign Template with number instead of text

Tags: php, rest, curl, docusignapi

Our problem: We're sending envelopes off to parties who are interested in applying for licenses. So far we've been successful at getting templates within the envelopes to prepopulate (using TextTabs) with information when a License Specialist sends the envelope off for signature if it's set up within our templates as text, but now we have a template that requires two fields to be numbers based on the fact that it has a formula that needs to do some calculating. Is there any way to have the template prepopulate using a number (using TextTabs, maybe?), any work around? We're using the REST API, PHP and cURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've created a DocuSign Template and are simply using the API to create/send Envelopes based on the Template, then you can simply modify the Data Field properties in the Template to indicate that it must contain a numeric value.  To do so, simply edit the field's properties to set **Mask** to "**Number**".

[image: Field Properties]

When interacting via the API with a data field that has **Mask** = **Number**, it will be of type **numberTab** -- i.e., it is no longer of type **textTab** in the API Request / Response.  For example, here's the response to a "Get Recipients" request that contains the "Quantity" field represented by the above screenshot:

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "tabs": {
                "numberTabs": [
                    {
                        "validationPattern": "",
                        "validationMessage": "",
                        "shared": "false",
                        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
                        "name": "Quantity",
                        "value": "",
                        "width": 42,
                        "required": "true",
                        "locked": "false",
                        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
                        "disableAutoSize": "false",
                        "tabLabel": "Quantity",
                        "bold": "false",
                        "italic": "false",
                        "underline": "false",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "recipientId": "f1b5d256-d85c-42d3-b081-913fb93e13a7",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": "71",
                        "yPosition": "37",
                        "tabId": "cf6367eb-de3d-4978-965e-2c29946989f2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "recipientId": "f1b5d256-d85c-42d3-b081-913fb93e13a7",
            "recipientIdGuid": "f1b5d256-d85c-42d3-b081-913fb93e13a7",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "Signer1",
            "status": "created",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "1"
}
```

Comment: You're the greatest person ever, Kim! This worked like a charm. Thank you so much.